# How to transfer data from a text file to a specific cell in Excel via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which transfers data from a textfile to an Excel sheet into column C.
Here is a code snippet.

```
Dim my_file As Integer
Dim text_line As String
Dim file_name As String
Dim i As Integer

file_name = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Test.txt"

my_file = FreeFile()
Open file_name For Input As my_file

i = 1

While Not EOF(my_file)
    Line Input #my_file, text_line
    Cells(i, "C").Value = text_line
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

But I want to transfer the data to C4.
How can I tweak the code to achieve my objective?

Comment: Hi here is the entire code, edited my post.

Comment: Well why does `i = 1`?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: `i` is used as the row number. Why do you have `i = 1`?

Comment: so if I change it to i = 4, it will write it into C4? got the code from the internet, so I don't know why i=1

Comment: Test it, and you'll see what the line `Cells(i, "C").Value = text_line` does. Highly suggest that you make an attempt to understand what the code is doing. If it helps, `F8` to step through the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Wrtiting the whole file starting from a certain cell C4 and going down with every line**

[image]

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myFile As Long
    Dim textLine As String
    Dim fileName As String

    fileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Test.txt"

    myFile = FreeFile()
    Open fileName For Input As myFile

    Dim writing As String
    Dim i As Long: i = 4
    While Not EOF(myFile)
        Line Input #myFile, textLine
        Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "C").Value = textLine
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

- **Wrtiting the whole file to a single cell**

This one takes all the lines from the `Test.txt` and writes them into `Range("C4")` of the first worksheet:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myFile As Long
    Dim textLine As String
    Dim fileName As String

    fileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Test.txt"

    myFile = FreeFile()
    Open fileName For Input As myFile

    Dim writing As String

    While Not EOF(myFile)
        Line Input #myFile, textLine
        writing = writing & vbCrLf & textLine
    Wend

    Worksheets(1).Cells(4, "C").Value = writing        

End Sub
```

It is done through the loop:

```
While Not EOF(myFile)
    Line Input #myFile, textLine
    writing = writing & vbCrLf & textLine
Wend
```

which writes every line to the variable `writing`, adding a new line whenever needed (`VbCrLf` is the new line). At the end `Worksheets(1).Cells(4, "C").Value = writing` writes the text of the file to the worksheet at `C4`.

Comment: Almost works, I still have one problem. The textfile has multiple lines. This code posts everything in C4. I would like to have 1 line in the textfile = 1 row in Excel. Do you know what I mean?